# Qt Set Background Image In QMdiArea

Tags: image, qt, background, center, qmdiarea

I'm creating a QMainWindow with a QMdiArea as the central widget. I have a logo/image I want to put in the center of the QMdiArea which will go over a colored background that I set, but I can't seem to figure out how.

So in the QMdiArea I need to set a background color, put the image on top of that color so that the rest of the background is colored, and center the image horizontally and vertically. So does anyone know how to do this?